# Is it possible to integrate @react-native-firebase/app with react-firebase-hooks?

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to integrate the @react-native-firebase/app package with react-firebase-hooks in my React Native application. However, I'm facing an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProvider' of undefined" when trying to use the getAuth method from the 'firebase/auth' package.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(credentials);
}

let app = firebase.app();
const authInstance = getAuth(app);
const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(authInstance);
```

When executing the above code, I receive the mentioned error. It seems that the object returned by the initializeApp method of '@react-native-firebase/app' is different from the object expected by the 'firebase/auth' package, resulting in the error when calling getAuth.

Is there a way to properly integrate '@react-native-firebase/app' with react-firebase-hooks? How can I resolve this error and use the useAuthState hook with '@react-native-firebase/app'?

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you can provide!

Comment: The last time I was playing around with firebase in react-native I found [react fire](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire) provided a lot nice hooks

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the `@react-native-firebase/*` family are made up of pseudo-SDKs, where it forwards requests to and receives responses from the native iOS and Android SDKs under the hood and returning those to the JavaScript engine. It's not a true like-for-like replacement for the JavaScript Web SDK and thus the typings don't always line up properly.

The latest version of `react-firebase-hooks` (and [last for a while](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/09bf06b28c82b4c3c1beabb1b32a8007232ed045/README.md#installation))  that supports React Native is [`react-firebase-hooks@3.0.5`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-hooks/v/3.0.5). As mentioned above, you may experience some type conflicts that you will need to resolve manually.

The reason support was dropped was because v9+ of the Firebase Web SDK drastically changed the API surface of the SDK which fell out of sync with the way that `@react-native-firebase/*` defines its pseudo-methods.